# Bootstrap data in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a angular one page application and I was wondering how to feed the app with data that are dynamically generated in the server side when the page first load.

Something like this:

```
var bootstrapValues = {
   totalNumberOfPosts: 345,
   postsPerPage: 10,
   // etc. etc.
}
```

What is a good way to enter this configuration hash into the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it in `run`

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http) {
    $http.get(configurationUrl).success(function(data) {
        $rootScope.bootstrapValues = data;
    }).error(function() {
    });
})
```

Comment: I know angular code can be really simple, but this simple? Since $http returns a promise, can we be certain that bootstrapValues has the data when the page first loads?

Comment: it does as the `success` executes. You said that, it's a promise.

Comment: It should be noted though that the success callback function could be run some time after the code in the run block has executed. In this time period `bootstrapValues` won't have a value. I think this goes against the idea of bootstrapping.